# Remote project in aptana

Tags: ftp, aptana, sftp, remoteapp

After last update I can't find any way to manage remote project via ftp or sftp.
Aptana has lost this feature or I can not find it? 
Does anyone know other ide with the same functionalities?
I tried netbeans but it downloads the entire project locally. I prefer the aptana way to provide just the list of all files without download them. Does Exist a way to make work netbeans as aptana for remote projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my initial walk through, it seems Aptana removed the connections node in the project tree.  If you select **Window -> Show View -> Remote** from the menu, you'll recieve a new remote tab with all your connections.

Additionally, if you have local files you previously promoted using '**Publish**', you can still do this in the same way. After selecting the '**Publish**' menu item, Aptana will ask for the remote connection from all your remotes to upload too.

Hope this helps!